# New fields not persisted in database after overriding FormType when register a new user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I am overriding the form type to register a user. All looks ok, but when I submit my form the new fields are not persisted in database.

I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md).

My ProfileType:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type;

//use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
//use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileType as BaseType;

class ProfileType extends BaseType
{
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->add('username', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Pseudo',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('firstname', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Prénom'
            ))
            ->add('lastname', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Nom'
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label'    => 'Email'
            ))
            ->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array(
                'label'    => 'Date d\'anniversaire',
                'required' => false,
                'data' => new \DateTime("01/01/1980")
            ))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'password', array(
                'label'    => 'Password'
            ))
            ->add('phone', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Téléphone',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('adress', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Adresse',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('zip', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Code postale',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('city', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Ville',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('newsletter', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'    => 'newsletter',
                'required' => false
            ))
            #hidden
            ->add('website', 'hidden', array(
                'label'    => 'website',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('biography', 'hidden', array(
                'label'    => 'biography',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('locale', 'hidden', array(
                'label'    => 'locale',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('timezone', 'hidden', array(
                'label'    => 'Timezone',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('gender', 'hidden', array(
                'label'    => 'Civilité',
                'required' => false
            ))
        ;
//        var_dump($builder);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'intention'  => 'profile',
            'label' => 'Edit Profile'
        ));
    }

//    public function getParent()
//    {
//        return 'fos_user_registration';
//    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'application_sonata_user_profile';
    }
}
```

My user class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;
/**
 * Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="search_idx", columns={"username", "email"})}))
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="username.already.exist" )
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="email.already.exist" )
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $zip;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adress", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $adress;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="newsletter", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $newsletter;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set zip
     *
     * @param string $zip
     * @return FosUserUser
     */
    public function setZip($zip)
    {
        $this->zip = $zip;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zip
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getZip()
    {
        return $this->zip;
    }

    /**
     * Set adress
     *
     * @param string $adress
     * @return FosUserUser
     */
    public function setAdress($adress)
    {
        $this->adress = $adress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdress()
    {
        return $this->adress;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return FosUserUser
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set Newsletter
     *
     * @param boolean $newsletter
     * @return FosUserUser
     */
    public function setNewsletter($newsletter)
    {
        $this->newsletter = $newsletter;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Newsletter
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getNewsletter()
    {
        return $this->newsletter;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a just created properties of the entity and you are using the metadata cache, the doctrine still doesn't aware about these new properties. Just try to clear the metadata cache.

Comment: I try this :  php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result but it does not change something.

Comment: If the metadata stores in the APC, it's useless to clear the cache through the "doctrine:cache:clear-metadata". The easier way is to restart the PHP-FPM or the Apache server if you are using the PHP as an extension.

Comment: Thank you for your help but nothing change.

Comment: I can only propose to make sure, have you created the migration and the migration has been applied.

Comment: I did not use. Why I need to use it? I am in the correct form (all the fields are only in one entity and displayed correctly). I will check again but I do not know what is wrong...

Comment: I mean, it is necessary if you've just added a new fields into the entity... Try to "var_dump" the entity just before persisting. Is it contains the data you need ?

Comment: I did a var_dump before persisting and the datas are in the different fields :  object(Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User)[1491]
  protected 'id' => int 777
  protected 'zip' => string '09922' (length=5)
  protected 'adress' => string 'flknvlkfnvn' (length=11)
  protected 'city' => string 'fknvklnvf' (length=9)
  private 'newsletter' => boolean true